# I want to fix websocket on localhost

Tags: laravel, websocket, localhost

I am running my web app on localhost and I have need to use ns so that chat and messaging, etc could work! now the WebSocket filed to connect! how can I fix that on localhost? anyone?

Comment: What websocket server are you using? How is it failing? Have you poked at https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pusher.com. I use it for my local development. It is free and works great. It is already supported by Laravel just read this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#pusher-channels